# How can I use cached images in an AJAX response?

Tags: images, ajax, jquery, headers, cache

`WP_AJAX` [includes no-cache headers](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/d1ac7170dc78f3fd7512fbedd71c7329fb58e253/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php#L42) with its responses. I'm using Ajax to fetch part of a shopping cart, which includes little image thumbnails. On each Ajax request, these are replaced and we can see them window-shading down, which looks wack and wastes bandwidth. Is there a way that those images can be cached without caching the whole response?

I can filter the headers, or adjust the Ajax call, or maybe do something downstream at CloudFlare, but this isn't my area of expertise and could use some help. Thanks!